# Any there Disadvantages to Ignoring the Completion of a Future?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka

I would like to run some code asynchronously, in a fire-and-forget way, without using an actor. Is there any problem with doing the following?

```
def myAsyncCode = {
  future{
    // Do something
  }
}

def myCaller{
  myAsyncCode
  // continue doing something else
}
```

As a beginner with futures, I am not sure whether ignoring their completion would produce memory leaks, or have other adverse effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem with that, except of course, if you want to deal specifically with failures.

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to just forget and ignore the future, rather than deal with failure.

Comment: Additional caveat, don't exit.